# What does it mean by 'bringing him gasping to all fours' in Harry potter?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Immediately, his insides started writhing as though he'd just swallowed live snakes -- doubled up, he wondered whether he was going to be sick -- then a burning sensation spread rapidly form his stomach to the very ends of his fingers and toes -- next, **bringing him gasping to all fours,** came to a horrible melting feeling, as the skin all over his body bubbled like hot wax -- and before their eyes, his hands began to grow, the fingers thickened, the knuckles were bulging like bolts -- his shoulders stretched painfully and a prickling on his forehead told him that his hair was creeping down toward his eyebrows -- his robes ripped as his chest expanded like a barrel bursting its hoops -- his feet were agony in shoes four sizes too small
>
> *Harry potter and the chamber of secrets*

It is the description of the feeling of drinking Polyjuice Potion, which makes someone into a different person, from the point of view of Harry Potter turning into Gregory Goyle.

And I don't understand what 'bring him gasping to all fours' means, especially 'four'. Does four here mean number 4?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, it is not the number four. The expression is [*all fours*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/all-fours) (Dictionary.com):

> 1. all four limbs or extremities; the four legs or feet of an animal or both arms and both legs or both hands and both feet of a person:
>      *The cat rolled off the ledge but landed on all fours.*

A common, related expression is to be [*on all fours*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/all-fours) (Dictionary.com):

> 3. b. (of a person) on the hands and feet, or the hands and knees:
>      *I had to go on all fours to squeeze through the low opening.*

In the story, "bringing him gasping to all fours" means he was gasping as he was brought to his hands and knees.
Imagine this guy, but gasping and agonizing.

[image]

Comment: [Google Image Search lets you filter by licensing](https://www.google.com/search?q=crawling&safe=active&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS751US752&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=sur:fc&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjc0sqEtbTXAhXFz4MKHUVpCxsQpwUIHw&biw=1866&bih=966&dpr=0.9), so you can find an image specifically licensed for re-use (and won't need to use one with a watermark across it). It's under "Tools" then "Usage Rights".

Comment: *technically* it is a reference to the number four. Specifically, "all four limbs" which is what "all fours" refers to.